# Need help understanding ReferenceProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, referenceproperty

Say I have two classes:

```
class A(db.Model):

class B(db.Model):
    a_reference = ReferenceProperty(A)
```

I can now do the following:

```
a = A()
a.put()

b = B();
b.a_reference = a.key()

b.put()
```

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty) states the following two things:

> The ReferenceProperty value can be used as if it were a model instance, and the datastore entity will be fetched and the model instance created when it is first used in this way.

And later also states:

> An application can explicitly db.get() the value of a ReferenceProperty (which is a Key) to test whether the referenced entity exists.

So what does that mean? The value is a `key` but it can be used a model instance?

If I do:

```
a2 = b.a_reference
```

a2 will be of type `A`, not `key`. Does this mean that the variable `a_reference` will behave like a model instance until that instance is deleted, whereafter it will return a key (pointing to a non-existing instance)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ReferenceProperty will always try to return an instance of the class that the stored key points to. If the referenced object has been deleted, I believe that you get back None. [From the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html#References):

```
obj1 = obj2.reference

if not obj1:
    # Referenced entity was deleted.
```

If you want to get the key that was originally stored, you can use [get_value_for_datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property_get_value_for_datastore):

```
a = A()
a.put()

b = B();
b.a_reference = a.key()

b.put()

orginial_key = b.a_reference.get_value_for_datastore()
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit. Thank you for clarifying that for me.

Comment: In a quick experiment, trying to use a ReferenceProperty pointing to a deleted entity raised `Error` with the message "ReferenceProperty failed to be resolved", rather than returning `None`.

Comment: Excellent catch, @Wooble. That's something that really ought to be noted in the docs. Is it just me, or are the AppEngine docs somewhat not-so-methodical?